# Generalizing how well an arbitrary set approximates a number?

Tags: approximation, diophantine-approximation, weierstrass-approximation

Suppose $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I want a measure $\mu(x,A)$ that determines "how well" $x$ can be approximated by $A$?

For example, if $A=\mathbb{Q}$, we use the [irrationality measure](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html):

**Definition**

Let $x$ be a real number, and let $R$ be the set of positive real numbers $\mu$ for which

$$0<\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q^{\mu}}$$

has at most finitely many solutions $p/q$ for $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then the irrationality measure or irrationality exponent is defined as the "threshold" where $x$ is no longer approximable by the rational numbers.

$$\mu(x)=\inf\limits_{\mu\in R}\mu$$

In general notation, $\mu(x,\mathbb{Q})=\mu(x)$

However, if $x\in A$ (for this case, $x\in\mathbb{Q}$), I want $\mu(x,A)$ to equal infinity and other cases of $x$ to give the same result before as if $x\in A$, we don't have to approximate it with set $A$ (we could just take $x$).

I believe this can be done by changing the inequality $0<\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q^{\mu}}$ to

$$\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|\le \frac{1}{q^{\mu}}$$

> **Problem**
>
> I would like to find a similar $\mu$ for $A$ in general, which is similar to the irrationality measure.

For instance, consider $A=\left\{\sqrt{a}:a\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}$

If $x$ is a real number, I would like to find a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ where if $R$ is a set of positive real numbers $\mu$ then

$$\left|x-\frac{\sqrt{p}}{\sqrt{q}}\right|\le g(p,q)^{\mu}$$

has at most finitely many solutions $\sqrt{p}/\sqrt{q}$ for $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$\mu(x,A)=\inf\limits_{x\in R}\mu$$

> **Question 1:** In this case, should $g(p,q)=1/\sqrt{q}$ or should it be something else?

> **Question 2:** What about for other sets such as:

$$A=\left\{\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}:m,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$

$$A=\left\{\frac{e^\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right)}{\ln(c)}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z},c\in\mathbb{N}+1\right\}$$

$$A=\text{Irrationals}$$

I expect for most $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\mu(x,A)$ should range between one and two?

Comment: To do what you want, you cannot simply take a set $A$, but you also have to choose some form of "classification" of the elements of $A$. For example, with the irrationality measure, you take $\mathbb Q$ and you "classify" each rational number as follows: $r\in\mathbb Q$ is assigned the "class" $q$ where $q$ is the smallest natural number such that $r = \frac{p}q$ for some $p\in\mathbb Z$. Afterwards you set $\mu(x, A)$ as the infimum of $R$ where $R=\{\mu\in]0,\infty[: \exists\text{only finitely many } a\in A\text{ with class } q(a)\in\mathbb N\text{ s.t. }\lvert x-a\rvert\le q(a)^{-\mu}\}$.

Comment: How you do this classification for some given $A$ is completely up to you, however, and as exercise you may become creative and find multiple ways for a given set $A$ :)

Comment: About question 1: Choosing $g(p,q)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{q}}$ is equivalent to $g(p,q)=\frac 1q$, since both choices lead to the same $\mu$ up to multiplication with the constant $2$.

Comment: One thing I haven’t checked is what the difference is between taking $\le$ in the definition of $R$ (as I stated it) and $<$ (as usually stated in the literature).

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch To double check, if $A=\left\{\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$, how should $\mu(x,A)$ be defined?

Comment: It depends on how you want to define your classes for this particular set! I don’t know of a good way to do this systematically.